# I have a trouble with parsing a table in a web page

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract one table from the web page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018%E2%80%9319_Premier_League) by using selenium and BeautifulSoup.

But I am stuck with parsing table.
I want just one table from the web page which is "League table" but whatever I've tried, I got error messages.

Here are my code that I've tried.

```
 import selenium 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver.get("https://google.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
elem.send_keys("2018 epl")
elem.submit()
try:
   print(driver.title)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Wikipedia").click()
website = requests.get(driver.current_url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(website, 'html.parser')
```

And then I'm facing trouble..
I've tried several codes, one of them are below.

```
rows=soup.find_all('td')
```

So can you help me to complete my code?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: You're mentioning Wikipedia page issue but your code is more relevant to google search. Can you provide a relevant example that would go straignt to the page you have mentioned and attempts to parse the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use pandas read_html and extract via appropriate index. I will however show using the :has selector for bs4 4.7.1 + to ensure you select h2 that has id League_table then immediate sibling combinator to get adjacent table

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018%E2%80%9319_Premier_League')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('h2:has(#League_table) + table')))
print(table)
```

---

Just read_html

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018%E2%80%9319_Premier_League')
print(tables[4])
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !! This is what I exactly want !! I actually try to use loop process so I need to specifying exact table name. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will help you start:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

respond = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018%E2%80%9319_Premier_League')
soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the table by using this code below your code.

`soup.body.find_all("table", class_="wikitable")[3]`

I found the table by using trial and error method i.e first see the class of the table and then use find_all and then list individual items and verifying the output.